# FileSaver.js can't specify the charset

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I'm using a FilseSaver.js to save a rtf file. This is working fine.

However when I'm using special chars, it goes wrong... The charset automatically "changes" from ansi to utf-8 and characters aren't displayed right in the rtf document.

I've tried "forcing" ansi, but it seems like all browsers ignore this setting?

Here is a part of my script:

```
var blob = new Blob([rtf], {type: "application/rtf;charset=windows-1252"});
saveAs(blob, filename);
```

This can be fixed by converting my special characters to unicode of hex characters. However using the correct charset seems simpler. Why isn't my script working and how should I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same problem, and it seems there's no possibility of stating the charset in the constructor, other than to manually encode your data into the encoding you need.

See this issue https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/14